# ActionFuntion not rerendering data on UI

Tags: apex, visualforce, rerender

Visualforce :

```
<apex:page id="ContactSearchPage" controller="ContactSearchController" sidebar="false" showHeader="false"
           standardStylesheets="false" showChat="false" docType="html-5.0">
    <c:FrameworkBaseComponent_CF boolCFBaseStyle="true" boolCFDataTables="true" boolCFStyle="true"/>


    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageMessages id="errors"/>
        <script type="text/javascript">
      function doSearch() {
        searchServer(
          document.getElementById("firstName").value,
          document.getElementById("lastName").value
          );
      }
      </script>
        <apex:actionFunction name="searchServer" action="{!runSearch}" rerender="results">
            <apex:param name="firstName" value="" />
            <apex:param name="lastName" value="" />
        </apex:actionFunction>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputText">First Name</label><input id="firstName" type="text" name="inputText"
                                                                        class="form-control"
                                                                        placeholder="Enter first name"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputText2">Last Name</label><input id="lastName" type="text" name="inputText2"
                                                                        class="form-control"
                                                                        placeholder="Enter last name"
                                                                        validate-required-error-message="Required field."/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button class ="btn btn-primary btn-md btn-block" onClick="doSearch()" title="Search" rerender="results">Search</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-md btn-block" id="newcontactbutton" type="button" style="display : none">New Contact
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    <div class="customDivider"/>
    <apex:pageBlock title="Search Results" id="results">
        <div id="collapse" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <apex:dataTable value="{!contactWrapperForDemos}" var="objRecord" id="theTable"
                                rowClasses="odd, even" styleClass="display dataTable-full">
                    <apex:column value="{!objRecord.firstName}" headerValue="First Name"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!objRecord.lastName}" headerValue="Last Name"/>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Link to Contact Page">
                        <apex:outputLink value="{!objRecord.url}">{!objRecord.firstName}</apex:outputLink>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column value="{!objRecord.additionalData}" headerValue="Additional Information"/>
                </apex:dataTable>
            </div>
        </div>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Controller :

```
public class ContactSearchController {

        // the collection of contacts to display
        public List<ContactWrapperForDemo> contactWrapperForDemos { get; set; }

        private transient List<Contact> contacts;

        private transient String soql;

        public ContactSearchController() {
            //runSearch();
        }

        // runs the search with parameters passed via Javascript
        public PageReference runSearch() {

            String firstName = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('firstName');
            String lastName = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('lastName');

            soql = 'select Id, firstname, lastname from contact where account.name != null';
            /*if (firstName != null && !firstName.equals(''))
                soql += ' and firstname LIKE '+String.escapeSingleQuotes(firstName)+'%';
            if (lastName != null && !lastName.equals(''))
                soql += ' and lastname LIKE '+String.escapeSingleQuotes(lastName)+'%';*/


            runQuery();

            return null;
        }

        // runs the actual query
        public void runQuery() {
            contactWrapperForDemos = new List<ContactWrapperForDemo>();
            try {
                System.debug('soql -> '+soql);
                contacts = Database.query(soql);
                IntegrationWrapperClass_CF cf = IntegrationClass_CF.callout(false, 'TestEndPoint', null, null, null, 500, null, true, null);

                // Deserialize the JSON string into collections of primitive data types.
                Map<String, Object> results = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(cf.strResponseBody);
                for (Contact c : contacts) {
                    String recordUrl = Url.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/' + c.Id;
                    /*Http http = new Http();
                    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
                    request.setEndpoint('callout:TestUrl');
                    request.setMethod('GET');
                    HttpResponse response = http.send(request);*/


                    contactWrapperForDemos.add(new ContactWrapperForDemo(c.FirstName, c.Id, c.LastName, recordUrl, (String) results.get('title')));


                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, e.getMessage()));
            }
        }
    }
```

I am returning the values and have kept debug points to check if there are any values `contactWrapperForDemos` and the values are there.
When I click the search button the block refreshes but no data is shown.
There are no exceptions also.

If I uncomment this line : `//runSearch();` then I can see the data in UI, but now with button onclick.

Comment: why you are not using apex:commandButton or apex:inputText? Secondly in the `button` there is `rerender` which is not needed since you are using rerender in actionFunction

Comment: tried removing the `rerender`, it does not work even then

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be getting an error on the page. You should check the debug logs and also rerender the **errors** pageMessages.

Also, Can you wrap apex:dataTable in the apex:outputPanel and rerender that output panel instead?

Just checked that your styling might not be working because of the new addition of output panel in the code block. You will have to update your styling in the component included at the top to match with this new relative xpaths.

Comment: As already mentioned no error message any where and debug statement does return the list : 13:50:30.0 (963330759)|USER_DEBUG|[57]|DEBUG|(ContactWrapperForDemo:[Id=0037F0000023BN0QAM, additionalData=qui est esse, firstName=Andy, lastName=Young, url=https://nagesingh-dev-ed--c.ap5.visual.force.com/0037F0000023BN0QAM])

Comment: Can you wrap apex:dataTable in the apex:outputPanel and rerender that output panel instead?

Comment: Yes @Naval I had changed my code already to this, this works but it removes all the css styling.

Answer (score 0):

This works but it removes all the styling:

```
       <apex:outputPanel id="showData">
            <apex:dataTable value="{!lstContactWrapper}" var="eachContactWrapper"
                            rowClasses="odd, even" styleClass="display dataTable-full">
                <apex:column value="{!eachContactWrapper.strFirstName}" headerValue="First Name"/>
                <apex:column value="{!eachContactWrapper.strLastName}" headerValue="Last Name"/>
                <apex:column headerValue="Link to Contact Page">
                    <apex:outputLink
                            value="{!eachContactWrapper.strUrl}">{!eachContactWrapper.strFirstName} {!eachContactWrapper.strLastName}</apex:outputLink>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column value="{!eachContactWrapper.strAdditionalData}" headerValue="Additional Information"/>
            </apex:dataTable>
        </apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: It's because you have styling included as the component and that styling is not dynamic. It's targetting the elements relatively. You will have to change the styling as per new html code.

Comment: Sorry I was not able to understand what you meant, can you please explain it once more.

Comment: I had to recreate the styling but it displays the old style for a split second